# Integration by parts for $\int \frac{f'}{f} dx$

Tags: calculus

The correct answer to the integral above should be $\int \frac{f'}{f} dx= \ln(f)$. Yet if one applies integration by parts according to

$\int u \frac{dv}{dx} = u v - \int v \frac{du}{dx} dx$

then setting $u = \frac{1}{f}$ and $v=f$ yields

$\int \frac{f'}{f} dx = f\frac{1}{f}  - \int f \left(-\frac{f'}{f^2}\right) dx = 1 + \int \frac{f'}{f} dx$

or 0 = 1. What's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The jump to $0=1$ is not correct. The antiderivatives on either side are equivalent *up to a constant*.

Comment: This is why writing "$+C$" is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx= \log |f(x)|+C$$
not $\log |f(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks, i guess that's the point!

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume, for simplicity, that $f$ is continuous over the interval $(a,b)$ (and nonzero).

If $c\in(a,b)$, an antiderivative of
$$
g(x)=\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
is
$$
G(x)=\int_c^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,dt
$$
Let's try integration by parts as you do:
$$
G(x)=\Bigl[f(t)\frac{1}{f(t)}\Bigr]_c^x - \int_c^x -\frac{f'(t)}{(f(t))^2}f(t)\,dt=1-1+\int_c^x \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}\,dt=G(x)
$$
A long tour that proves nothing.

When in doubt, use a *particular* antiderivative; you're not considering that antiderivatives (over an interval) are defined up to an additive constant, so what you actually proved is that $0$ and $1$ differ by a constant. Not really a surprise, is it?